# hashCode methods in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

is that normal that I have the same hashcode for both ?? I'm confuse. I thought the hashcode was unique.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> t = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    t.put("one", 123);
    t.put("two", 123);

    System.out.println(t.get("one").hashCode());
    System.out.println(t.get("two").hashCode());
}
```

output

```
123
123
```

Comment: what is your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `123` and `123` has the same hashcode because these are two [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)s with the same `int` value:

```
t.get("one") // returns an Integer with an int value of 123
t.get("two") // returns an Integer with an int value of 123
```

From the *[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode())* (`Integer.hashCode()`):

> a hash code value for this object, equal to the primitive int value
>   represented by this Integer object.

When in doubt use the source:

```
     /**
  743        * Returns a hash code for this {@code Integer}.
  744        *
  745        * @return  a hash code value for this object, equal to the
  746        *          primitive {@code int} value represented by this
  747        *          {@code Integer} object.
  748        */
  749       public int hashCode() {
  750           return value;
  751       }
```

Answer (score 0):

strong textObjects that are equal must have the same hash code within a running process

Please note that this does not imply the following common misconceptions:

```
Unequal objects must have different hash codes – WRONG!
Objects with the same hash code must be equal – WRONG!
```

[image]

The contract allows for unequal objects to share the same hash code, such as the **“A“** and **“µ”** objects in the sketch above.

This is obvious because the number of possible distinct objects is usually bigger than the number of possible hash codes (2^32).